# Terminal outputting: manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, npm, terminal

While trying to run a specific bash script, I get the following output:

```
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
Running node v4.8.5 (npm v2.15.11)
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

The content of the script is the following:

```
 #!/bin/bash

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
cd /home/desktop/folder/subfolder && nvm exec 4.8.5 node app.js
```

If I write a small bash script, using echo or the like, the error doesn't occure.
I haven't seen this error before. What is the cause?
Other answers make it seem like an encoding error. I am using US.UTF-8.

Comment: If you are trying to ssh from mac to ubuntu, it can be helpful https://askubuntu.com/a/1489608/778170

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me today

```
echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Resource from https://gist.github.com/zeroc0d3/9d5333d542f7d1bc997d902ac17cd034

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 today as well.